# Is it possible to insert a string into PM2 logs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pm2

After a user logs in, I'd like to add their user ID to the log line generated by PM2 when a user navigates to any route.

Comment: Why are you trying to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to use process.stdout.write() instead of console.log(), which was adding a newline to the log line.